# iPhone in app purchase subscription to web server data. How should I auth?

Tags: iphone, web-services, authentication, in-app-purchase

I'm working on an app that will provide data from a web server to users but only if they've bought an in app purchase subscription. I understand the basics of IAPs but how do I securely make sure the data from the server is only accessible to the app, and only if the subscription has been purchased? I don't want to make the user set up an account, I just want to auth the app/purchase securely.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upload store receipts to your server, to be able to check them on Apple's site. And, with request you should upload phone identifier. And, of course, store somewhere in the database. After all, you will have information about which phone id has access to subscription.
And, when you will request subscription-related info from your server, you'll be able to check who has acces (via phone id) and who hasn't.

Comment: you have to make your IAPs available for up to 5 devices with the same itunes account. how do you check that this user has active subscription when he uses your app on a new device ?

Comment: When app will be installed, Apple will send restored transactions information to your app, and app will be able to insert that info into database as well.

Comment: Restored transactions are not implemented by StoreKit for *subscriptions* (it is for *auto renew* subscription) so this will not work for the scope this question covers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to use subscription model too with IAP.

AFAIK, you **SHOULD NOT** use a unique phone identifier like the IMEI of the phone to identify the user on your server. According to the Apple documentation, you MUST provide a way so that an user can restore his subscriptions on **several** devices!

Besides, a call to *restoreCompletedTransactions* of the *SKPaymentQueue* will restore **ONLY** nonconsumable products! Subscriptions are not supported by this method.

See these links :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2009/tn2259.html (section « Frequently Asked Questions », point 10)

[iPhone - How to recognize the iTunes user of my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905955/iphone-how-to-recognize-the-itunes-user-of-my-app)

The only way I know is to use a login/password to identify the user on the web server but this could be quite ugly...
However, if someone know another way, could he describe his solution ?

Comment: thanks, some good reading there. Will have to think carefully about this.